# git alias with multiple options not working

Tags: git

I'm using this `git` command to display pretty list of commits

`git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" -15`

what I wanted to do is to use an `alias` to this command

this is what i added in my `.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
    ls = log --pretty=format:"%h %s" -15
```

but when i try `git ls`, i got this error

```
$ git ls
fatal: ambiguous argument '%s': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

is there something i miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change double quotes to single quotes.

```
ls = log --pretty=format:'%h %s' -15
```

works for me.